# Conversion of matlab to python

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am converting matlab code to python code. I would like to convert the following matlab's code to python:

```
im = permute(single(im_in(:,:,[3,2,1])),[2 1 3]);
```

How can I do that? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the transpose function from numpy in a similar fashion:

`im = np.transpose(im_in[:,:,[2,1,0]],(1,0,2))`

[Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) you can find the documentation